# How to plot lines according to some condition?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was solving a coding problem and came across this one. It states : 
We have an infinitely planar cartesian coordinate system on which N points are plotted. Cartesian coordinates of the point I am represented by (Xi, Yi).
Now we want to draw (N-1) line segments which may have arbitrary lengths and the points need not lie on the lines. The slope of each line must be 1 or -1.

Let's denote the minimum distance we have to walk from a point I to reach a line by `Di` and let's say `a = max(D1, D2, D3,..., DN)`. We want this distance to be minimum as possible.

Thus we have to plot lines in such a way that it minimizes 'a' and compute a*sqrt(2)

Constraints :
`1 <= T <= 100

2 <= N <= 10^4

|Xi|, |Yi| <= 10^9 for each valid i`
Here T denotes number of test cases.

Sample input 1 :
N = 3
Points : (0,0) , (0,1) , (0,-1)

Sample output 1 :
0.5
Explanation: We should draw lines described by equations y−x+0.5=0 and y−x−0.5=0

Sample input 2 :
N = 3
Points : (0,1) , (1,0) , (-1,0)

Sample output 2 :
0
Explanation: We should draw lines described by equations y−x−1=0 and y+x−1=0

Output format : 
For each test case, print a single line containing one real number — the minimum distance a multiplied by sqrt(2). Your answer will be considered correct if its absolute or relative error does not exceed 10^(-6).

Time limit: 1 sec

My understanding is as the slopes are 1 or -1 the equations of the lines would be y = x + c or y = -x + c and we just have to find the y-intercept c which minimizes the distance 'a' in the problem. Also, the minimum distance from a point to the line is the length of the perpendicular to the line.
So I am having difficulty to devise an algorithm which will check all possible values of 'c' and find the optimal one.

Comment: I think this might be better to post on https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: What did you try? How far did you get? We can only help you if you tell us what you already know and what you don't.

Comment: Wouldn't the best answer be to have each line segment i go through point i?

Comment: Given that you have N points and N-1 lines, you can have N-2 lines go through N-2 points. That leaves 2 points and 1 line.

Comment: @user3386109 I doubt that would work, as we need to minimize the distance from a point to a line, so if the points are too far away, it would give wrong ans. 
Anyway please feel free to provide an implementation of the same :)

Comment: @J.AntonioPerez We have N-1 lines and N points so each line won't be able to go through all points.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with c++. Please remove the tag.

Comment: My implementation is giving correct answer for small values of N and (x,y) but gives wring answer for large values mentioned in the constraints. If someone could help me figure out what is going on it would be a great help.

Comment: You should complete your code so that people can directly compile and test it. You can also suppress the `abs()` used for `ans` calculation, as it is useless.

Comment: Finally, I got correct answers to all questions simply by using `std::setprecision(12)`. However, I got a time limit issue, 1.01s instead of 1s.

Comment: @Damien Yes I got it. Thanks a lot for your help.Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Let us denote `M[i]` the point `(x[i], y[i])`

The fist step is to compute the distance between a point `M(x, y)` and a line `D`, slope of which is equal to `+/-1`.

Let us denote `D` and `D'` the lines
`D: y + x + c = 0`
`D': y - x + c = 0`

Then, a few calculations allow to show that

- the distance between `M` and `D` is equal to `d(M, D) = abs(y + x + c)/sqrt(2)`
- the distance between `M` and `D'` is equal to `d(M, D') = abs(y - x + c)/sqrt(2)`

Let us now consider two different points, for example `M[0]` and `M[1]`, and let us calculate the minimum distance between these two points and a line `D` of parameter `c` and slope `+/-1`.

Formally, we have two find the minimum, over `c` and slope, of
`max(d(M[0], D), d(M[1], D))`

If the slope is `-1`, i.e. if the equation is `y+x+c=0`, one can easily show the the optimum `c` parameter is equal to

`c = -(x0 + y0 + x1 + y1)/2`

The corresponding distance is equal to `abs(x0+y0-x1-y1)/(2*sqrt(2))`

If the slope is `1`, i.e. if the equation is `y-x+c=0`, one can show the the optimum `c` parameter is equal to

`c = (x0 - y0 + x1 - y1)/2`

The corresponding distance is equal to `abs(y0 - x0 - y1 + x1)/(2*sqrt(2))`

Therefore, the minimum distance from these two points to an *optimal* line is the minimum of the previous two distances.

This leads to define the following quantities, for each points `M[i]`:

- `a|i] = y[i] - x[i]`
- `b[i] = y[i] + x[i]`

And then to define a distance between points `M[i]` and `M[j]` as :

`d(M[i], M[j]) = min (abs(b[i]-b[j]), abs(a[i]-a[j]))`

The proposed algorithm consists in finding the pair `(M[i], M[j])` such that this distance is minimized.

Then the wanted result is equal to half this distance.

This corresponds to consider that a line will pass through the *distant* points (according to the defined distance), except the two closest ones, for which we will draw a line just in between.

(EDIT)

The complexity is not O(n^2) as previously stated.
The complexity to find the min of `d(M[i], M[j])` is O(N logN).
This is obtained by sorting the `a[i]` and to get the min of the differences between adjacent values, i.e. `min(a[i+1] - a[i])`.
Then by doing the same for the `b[i]`, and finally taking the minimum of the two obtained values.

Comment: This is very close, but it's possible to reduce the complexity to less than O(N^2).

Comment: @user3386109 Effectively. I went too fast. If I am not wrong, we can get the optimum pair by sorting the `a[i]` and independently the `b[i]`. We then get a O(N logN) complexity. Is it what you were thinking of ?

Comment: Yup, that's exactly what I was thinking.

Comment: @Damien Can you please provide a sample implementation of the proposed algorithm, as mine is giving some errors for the same.

Comment: What kind of error? On the simple test cases that you provided? I don't have time now to work on a implementation. If you provide your own implementation, I will have a look at it

Comment: Concerning the speed: you don't need to use abs to calculate `diff[]`, and you don't need to sort it to get the min (you can use `std::min`). You can also avoid introducing index `k`. Final `k` equals `n-1`. Concerning correctness, the issue is to find a test case that gives a bad result. You could try to invent some simple cases and test them.

Comment: The time limit issue is solved, but still gives wrong answer for some of test cases.

Comment: For small values of N and (x,y) it is giving correct answer (N<=5 and  |x|,|y| <= 10) but for large values, the constraints mentioned above it gives wrong answer. I doubt it is a corner case